# Escaping column effect

Tags: css

I am using [css columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts) with the counter set to two columns. The elements I am displaying inside these columns have links and on mouseover I am displaying a popover div that I am using to display extra information.

The problem is that the popover div can be outside the element dimension hence the column dimension. This hides part of the popover because the column is set to specific width and hides any parts that are larger. Furthermore if the popover is at the bottom of column 1 it will partly be displayed at the bottom of column 1 and partly at the top of column 2.

Is there a way to tell an element which is located inside a column to behave as it is not inside the column hence escaping the column effects?

Comment: Are you using `overflow` styling rules anywhere on the column elements?

Comment: No, not using any overflow. It looks like I will need to move the popover outside of the elements. I was hoping this was possible since I wanted the popover to be part of the element because it´s a component.

Comment: You could try using `overflow: visible` because that would force the popover to be shown fully outside the parents dimensions.